# Kubernetes rolling update by only changing env variables

Tags: kubernetes

I want to perform rolling update in Kubernetes by only changing env variables. like changing env variable from `CACHE_SIZE=10` to

```
CACHE_SIZE=100
```

while the base image is the same.

Issue: i don't want to delete pod and service. Just want to restart all the pods with new env variable.

UPDATE : Want to change the env variable via kubernetes API

Comment: What's the question and what is the problem you are facing? Please elaborate.

Comment: How are you changing this ENV variable? is it part of the deployment template? or read from ConfigMaps or Secrets?

Comment: from kubernetes API

Comment: What do you mean by *"from kubernetes API"*. Basically every execution of `kubectl` command makes some kind of call to the **kubernetes API**.

Comment: kubernetes rest api calls

Answer (score 0):

The Deployment system checksums the entire pod template provided triggers a rolling update on any change, env var or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You could restart the deployment with a command like

```sh
kubectl -n your-name-space rollout restart deployment/your-deployment
```

This will keep using the same image tag but will restart/recreate the pod with the new ENV variables assuming you are reading it from `Secrets` or `ConfigMaps`.

Answer (score 0):

> Issue: i don't want to delete pod and service. Just want to restart
>   all the pods with new env variable.

First of all **there is not such a thing as Pod restart** in a literal sense. It may sound quite confusing as you can often hear/read about Pod restart e.g. in context of `Pod` `restartPolicy`. Pods are designed as relatively ephemeral, disposable entities and restarting a `Pod` basically means recreating it.

No matter how you provide your env variables, either using ConfigMap that is meant to be read by your `Pods` or directly in `Pod` template in `Deployment` definition, `Pods` need to be recreated. They will be technically same `Pods` based on the same template, same image etc. but they will be completely new instances with their own unique names.

As to `Service` you don't have to delete it. Changes made in `Pod` template specification and recreating them don't affect the `Service`. Same when `Pods` are recreated to re-read changed `Secrets` or `ConfigMaps`.